std::length_error in AlignGraph during Multithreaded Execution
I'm encountering a std::length_error in a multithreaded C++ program, AlignGraph, while running it inside a Docker container. The error seems to occur during string manipulation (specifically using std::string::append) in one of the threads. The program works by aligning genomic data using the NUCMER or BLAT tools, but during execution, it throws an error related to string length in one of the commands.
Running command:
Starting program: /opt/AlignGraph/AlignGraph/AlignGraph --read1 sample1.fasta --read2 sample2.fasta --contig /data/run/plentyofbugs_out/assembly/contigs.fasta --genome /data/reference_genome/GCA_013814885.1_ASM1381488v1_genomic.fna --distanceLow 100 --distanceHigh 1000 --extendedContig extendedContigs.fa --remainingContig remainingContigs.fa

After running in debugger i got.
Thread 3 "AlignGraph" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff72016c0 (LWP 91)]
__pthread_kill_implementation (no_tid=0, signo=6, threadid=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
warning: 44     ./nptl/pthread_kill.c: No such file or directory
(gdb) backtrace
#0  __pthread_kill_implementation (no_tid=0, signo=6, threadid=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
#1  __pthread_kill_internal (signo=6, threadid=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:78
#2  __GI___pthread_kill (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=signo@entry=6) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:89
#3  0x00007ffff7b3f26e in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/posix/raise.c:26
#4  0x00007ffff7b228ff in __GI_abort () at ./stdlib/abort.c:79
#5  0x00007ffff7ddeffe in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff7df3e9c in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x00007ffff7ddea49 in std::terminate() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x00007ffff7df4128 in __cxa_throw () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x00007ffff7de2381 in std::__throw_length_error(char const*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#10 0x0000555555562b51 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_check_length (__s=0x555555580071 "basic_string::append", __n2=6, __n1=0,
    this=0x7ffff7200b30) at /usr/include/c++/13/bits/allocator.h:184
#11 std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::append (__s=0x5555555802ce ".delta", this=0x7ffff7200b30) at /usr/include/c++/13/bits/basic_string.h:1473
#12 std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > (__rhs=0x5555555802ce ".delta", __lhs=...) at /usr/include/c++/13/bits/basic_string.h:3690
#13 task1 (arg=<optimized out>) at AlignGraph.cpp:3640
#14 0x00007ffff7b96a94 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/pthread_create.c:447
#15 0x00007ffff7c23c3c in clone3 () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone3.S:78

Code snippet around the line 3640:
3631 //NUCMER
3632                 for(chromosomeID = 0; chromosomeID < ins.numChromosomes; chromosomeID ++)
3633                 {
3634                         command = "nucmer tmp/_genome." + itoa(chromosomeID) + ".fa tmp/_contigs.fa -p tmp/_contigs_genome." + itoa(chromosomeID) + " > nucmer_doc.txt 2> nucmer_doc.txt";
3635                         if(system(command.c_str()) != 0)
3636                         {
3637                                 command = "touch tmp/_contigs_genome." + itoa(chromosomeID) + ".delta";
3638                                 system(command.c_str());
3639                         }
3640                         command = "tmp/_contigs_genome." + itoa(chromosomeID) + ".delta";
3641                         delta2psl(command);
3642                 }
3643         }
3644         else
3645         {
3646                 for(chromosomeID = 0; chromosomeID < ins.numChromosomes; chromosomeID ++)
3647                 {
3648                         command = "pblat tmp/_genome." + itoa(chromosomeID) + ".fa tmp/_contigs.fa -noHead tmp/_contigs_genome." + itoa(chromosomeID) + ".psl -fastMap -threads=8 > blat_doc.txt 2> blat_doc.txt";
3649                         if(system(command.c_str()) != 0)
3650                         {
3651                                 command = "blat tmp/_genome." + itoa(chromosomeID) + ".fa tmp/_contigs.fa -noHead tmp/_contigs_genome." + itoa(chromosomeID) + ".psl -fastMap > blat_doc.txt 2> blat_doc.txt";
3652                                 if(system(command.c_str()) != 0) {cout << "BLAT CALL FAILED!" << endl; exit(-1);}
3653                         }
3654                 }
3655         }
3656 }

I need help identifying the root cause of this error, particularly how to prevent the string length issue and what  changes I might need to make in the code to resolve it. Any guidance on debugging steps or suggestions for a minimal reproducible example would be appreciated!
I don’t have much experience with C/C++, and I’m unsure how to provide a reproducible example for debugging. I'm also not certain whether the issue stems from incorrect string handling or something else in the multi-threaded setup. I am running this within a Docker container, and the tool works fine locally outside the container.
You can take a look at the AlignGraph tool  https://github.com/baoe/AlignGraph/tree/master/AlignGraph.
I tried check weather it is a compilation issue and also i have tried very less input size file but it still throws error.

We're not going to look into external repositories or links, your question must be self contained. What you see is NOT a compilation issue but a runtime issue. You say you use multiple threads, and you point to code in an external library. However the problem is most likely in your own multithreaded code (which we cannot see). Unless a library EXPLICITLY states it is threadsafe, it will not be threadsafe. And this includes calls to std::string. Did you use any std::scoped_lock, std::shared_lock, std::unique_lock,  std::mutex or std::shared_mutex in your code? If not that's a place to start.

"Works fine sometimes or somewhere" is a classic sign of undefined behaviour. The code is clearly "research-grade" code, for personal use and for a specific paper. I would not expect it to work "out of the box", and a quick glance at the code suggests that problems are pretty likely.

@PepijnKramer There is no std::scoped_lock, std::shared_lock, std::unique_lock, std::mutex or std::shared_mutex in the code.

Then your code is not threadsafe and anything can happen. You really have to protect parts of your code against concurrent access. There is no free lunch when it comes to multithreading.

Thank you ! Please  can you guide further since i cannot make changes to the original code. I was thinking to make a wrapper or someting like that i can run along side of AlignGraph. I am looking for some thing like this ./my patch AlignGraph --read sample1 rest of the command . I hope you get my point. @PepijnKramer

I do not have the time to deep dive into your code or your use case. If you want to use the full power C++ then you will also have to learn how to use it (C++ is just that kind of language). But sure making a wrapper that will call the original library from within a critical section is an option. Another option is to use an executor (that will be able to run lambda expressions one by one on the same thread).

Thank you ! I will try to make an executor script. Thank you for your guidance.
@Pepijn Kramer
